# Network terminology "software / hardware address"

Tags: networking, terminology

What are the two concepts referring to in the field of computer networking? Does software address equal to IP address and hardware address equal to MAC address?

Comment: [Looks like it](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VQvhAN9iBuMC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22software+address%22+networking&source=bl&ots=kC0NM2XDmo&sig=JZ93z6pl6WkV7rntGmgc1pdlN_I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid0ra6w8XVAhVJb1AKHY5PDpIQ6AEIUzAE#v=onepage&q=%22software%20address%22%20networking&f=false)

Comment: In one term, YES. For any network interface, its software address is equal to IP address and its hardware address is equal to MAC address

Comment: @stuarted I really learned a lesson to search for Google Books when normal search can't give exact answers. Thanks also goes to Am_I_Helpful, yes you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the domain of TCP/IP network stack over ethernet, your understanding is correct. However, there were or are other network stacks such as Token Ring & IPX/SPX, the hardware & software addresses refer to a bit different but similar things.